# Чи є різниця між "відновний " і "відновлювальний"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Натикнувся на [статтю](http://uprom.info/news/other/infrastruktura/u-dnipri-zbuduyut-paralimpiyskiy-tsentr-vartistyu-40-milyoniv-dolariv), в якій згадується *«реабілітаційно-**відновний** спортивний центр у Дніпрі планують будувати…»*

Мені це слово здалося незвичним.

Словники мають як статтю [*відновний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidnovnyj), так і [*відновлювальний*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidnovljuvaljnyj), з повністю однаковою семантикою:

> Стосовний до відновлення.

Чи є між цими словами якась різниця? Цікавить, у першу чергу, контекст медичної галузі, але і дізнатися про інші контексти також було б цікаво.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В одному випадку йдеться про пасивну здатність, в іншому про активну.

Так, **відновний** це прикметник, що вказує на здатність бути підданим певній дії (тобто пасивну здатність). Тоді як **відновлювальний** - це прикметник, що вказує на призначення виконувати дію чи здатність/властивість виконувати дію (активну здатність). Тобто автор припустився помилки.

Дуже раджу цю статтю: Кочерга О., Пілецький В. *[ПРОЦЕСОВІ ПРИКМЕТНИКИ В НАУКОВІЙ МОВІ](http://r2u.org.ua/node/162)*, 2010

> Розглянуто структуру та способи творення процесових (віддієслівних)
>   прикметників на позначення активної та пасивної здатности об’єкта,
>   тобто здатности бути підданим дії (пасивна здатність) або призначення
>   виконувати дію чи здатність брати участь у процесі (активна
>   здатність).

Наведу два уривки:

1. > Віддієслівні прикметники з кінцевим -**овн**(ий) та пасивні дієприкметники
   >   минулого часу в двослівних найменуваннях об’єктів дії різняться
   >   семантично: *нехтовний член* — це той, що його можна викинути будь-коли,
   >   а *нехтуваний член* — це той, що ми його викидаємо у певний момент
   >   виконання дії; *регульовний* — такий, що його можна регулювати тоді,
   >   коли треба, а *регульований* — це той, що ми його регулюємо саме зараз
   >   або взагалі в певний проміжок часу виконання дії; *інтеґровний* — той,
   >   що його можна проінтеґрувати (і на то є низка критеріїв), *інтеґрований*
   >   — той, що його інтеґрування є предметом цього допису.
2. > На сьогодні вже майже зовсім втрачено відчуття семантичної відмінности
   >   між спільнокореневими прикметниками, що означають призначення до
   >   певної функції/дії (*рятувальний* човен, *фільтрувальний* пристрій,
   >   *гартувальний* розчин, *коксувальна* піч) та здатність/властивість
   >   виконувати дію (*рятівна* соломинка, *фільтрівний* ґрунт, *йонізівне*
   >   проміння, *гартівне* середовище). Прикметники, що вказують на
   >   призначення до дії, переважно творяться додаванням до дієслівної
   >   основи суфікса -**льн**- (*чита-льн-ий, роздава-льн-ий, фільтрува-льн-ий,
   >   гостри-льн-ий, дої-льн-ий*), а прикметники, що означають здатність
   >   предмета виконувати дію — передусім додаванням суфікса -**н**- до
   >   найпродуктивнішої в науковій мові дієслівної твірної основи із
   >   суфіксом -**ува**- (*гарт-ува-ти — гарт-івн-ий, руйн-ува-ти — руйн-івн-ий*.
   >   У цих дієсловах -**ів**- — це трансформ суфікса основи -**ува**-, коли до
   >   нього приєднують суфікс -**н**-, пор. також пан-ува-ти — пан-ів+н(ий),
   >   кер-ува-ти — кер-ів+н(ий) (від суфікса -**ува**- відтинаємо кінцевий
   >   голосний **а**, а звук **у** чергуємо з **і**: гарт-ув(а)-ти — гартівний).

Comment: Тоді, можливо, перше речення вашої відповіді варто викласти у формі: «В одному випадку йдеться про здатність, в іншому про призначення» — мені здалося, що саме це мається на увазі?

Comment: @bytebuster, я використав термінологію зі статті. То обидві - здатності. Тобто або його можна відновити, або він відновлює. Мені здається призначення якось двояко можна зрозуміти.

Answer (score 4):

Можливо, [тонка й несхопна] різниця у більш активній чи пасивній позиції відповідно: "відновлювальний" як "той, що відновлює" (англ. recover**ing**, reconstruct**ing** [surgery], рос. восстанавл**ивающая**, возобновл**яющая** [хирургия]), однак "відновний" як "той, що піддається віднові; який [ще] можна відновити" (як "[не]відновні копалини", англ. [un]renew**able** fossils, рос. [не]возобнов**имые** ископаемые). Наприклад також "[не]відновний збиток від пожежі, потопу, російської агресії тощо".