# Суфікс дієслів ‑ува‑ чи що таке протяжні, наворотні?

Tags: суфікси

Шчо означає дїєслівний народсток *-ува-*?

Наприклад, найвідоміші словники як [СУМ-11](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) та [СУМ-20](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) їх не [дуже] розрізняють, результат:

---

Родичі-запитання

- [Чи є різниця між "відновний " і "відновлювальний"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/)
- [Як правильно "скористУйтесь" чи "скористАйтесь"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3017/)
- [Різниця між словами скористатися/скористуватися?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/)
- [«вИпробування» чи «випрОбування»?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/)

…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>[Норми української літературної мови](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/zmist) · [Олекса Синявський](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>

#### [§ 101. Наростки дієслівні: значіння і їх вживання](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky)

**5. ‑ува‑, ‑юва‑** (**‑у‑, ‑ю‑**) — дуже поширений в українських дієсловах наросток з різним значінням:

**а)** в дієсловах недоконаних від іменникових і прикметникових пнів: *дарувати* (*дарую*…), *порядкувати*, *мурувати*, *горювати*…, часто, між іншим, на означення того, хто що робить або чим він є, в якому стані перебуває: *учителювати*, *писарювати*, *гостювати*, *хазяйнувати*, г*осподарювати*, *голодувати*, *секретарювати*, *професорувати*, *козакувати*, *дівувати*, *парубкувати*, *вдовувати*, *кравцювати*, *чабанувати*, *гайдамакувати*, *марнувати*, *пильнувати*, *слабувати*, *радуватися*…, отже іноді ніби рівнобіжне з **‑и‑**: *господарювати* і *господарити*, *гайдамакувати* і *гайдамачити* тощо. Звичайно всі ці дієслова від іменників мають дуже відмінне значіння супроти дієслів основних того ж кореня, напр., *учити* далеко не те, що *учителювати* („бути в учителях, за вчителя“), *косити* не те, що *косарювати* („бути в косарях, за косаря“) і т. ін.

**б)** чималу вагу має цей наросток при творенні наворотних форм дієслів із протяжних: *вихваляти вихвалювати*…, *мордувати замордовувати*, *горювати загорьовувати*…, де, як бачимо, він буває і в подвоєній формі див. [§ 85](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_diyeslovo).

Усі наведені дієслівні наростки органічно звʼязані з творенням дієслівних форм як доконаности супроти недоконаности, наворотности супроти протяжности.

---

#### [§ 85. Протяжні — наворотні](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_diyeslovo)

Як бачимо ми з прикладу в § 83, форми недоконаности та доконаности не вичерпують усіх форм тривання дієслів. У межах, напр., самих недоконаних дієслів вирізняються окремі розряди тривання. Так, форми 1. й 2. в стовпці недоконаних форм (*несу* — *ношу*) це форми *протя́жности* й *на́воротности* дієслова, власне протяжности й наворотности дії, бо протяжна форма дієслова (*несу*) визначає тяглу і разову дію, при тім конкретнішу супроти дії повторної, кількаразової і при тім абстрактнішої, що означується наворотною формою (*ношу*). Коли недоконаність ми умовно означили лінією супроти доконаности, означеної крапкою, то наворотність недоконаних дієслів можна означити кількома лініями супроти протяжности:

> *нести —, а носити — — — —*

Але таке розрізнення протяжности й наворотности ми спостерігаємо в невеликому числі дієслів, напр.:

> *везти — возити
>
> вести — водити
>
> брести — бродити
>
> летіти — літати
>
> гонити (гнати) — ганяти
>
> ломити — ламати
>
> котити — качати
>
> пливти — плавати
>
> лізти — лазити*

деякі інші. Іноді ці форми різняться тільки наростком:

> *тягти — тягати
>
> бігти — бігати*

Але в величезній більшості дієслів ці форми протяжности й наворотности не розрізняються, напр., ми не можемо назвати ні протяжними, ні наворотними недоконані дієслова *писати*, *лити*, *варити*, *читати*, *співати*, *гуляти*, *стрибати*, *пасти*, *прясти*, *журитися* і т. ін.

Відповідно до протяжности й наворотности недоконаних форм (*нести* — *носити*, або в умовнім означенні — і — — — —) і в доконаних формах типу *понесу* — *поношу* можна вирізняти разову й кількаразову дію, отже в схематичному означенні

> . . та . . . .

Таким чином 1. й 2., 6. й 7. форми дієслова *нести* (§ 83) укладаються в схемі:

> ```
> —       | .  
> — — — — | . . . .
> ```

А щодо доконаних відповідників до наведених угорі дієслів типу *писати*, *лити*, *варити*… то, звичайно, і в них не можна вирізняти відтінків разовости й кільказразовости, бо такі форми, як *написати*, *полити*, *зварити*…, однаково відповідають і таким, як *понести*, і таким, як *поносити* тощо.

Відтінки разовости і кількаразовости в таких дієслівних формах, як *понести*, *винести*, *принести*… з одного боку і *поноси́ти*, *наноси́ти*, *доноси́ти*… з другого, добре даються пізнати з тих природних супровідних слів, що звичайно бувають при тих формах напр., на разовість дії вказують такі слова, як *раз*, *зара́з*, природні при перших формах (*понесу раз*, *винесу раз*, *перенесу раз*, *піднесу раз*…), але на кількаразовість дії при дієсловах других указують такі слова, як *багато* (*поношу багато*, *наношу багато*, *переношу багато*…).

Із трьох інших недоконаних форм тривання 3. і 4. (див. § 83) майже однозначні (*приношати* відчувається як архаїзм), але два відтінки з усієї цієї групи (3., 4. і 5.) сприросткованих недоконаних форм подекуди розрізняється також як форми протяжні й наворотні, хоч і не так виразно, як у несприросткованих, тобто *нести* — *носити* виразніше розрізняються, як *вино́сити* — *виношувати*, дарма що основа протиставлення їх — протяжність і наворотність — у них та сама. А про відношення самих двох недоконаних протяжних форм, себто *нести* до *вино́сити*, *перено́сити*… та двох наворотних, себто *носити* до *виношувати*, *доношувати*…, можна сказати, що ці другі (сприростковані) наворотні форми супроти перших відзначаються тільки більшою конкретністю, звуженістю значіння дієслів, тобто тим, що в них внесли приростки і що власне вже до тривання й не стосується.

Друга протяжність — наворотність (типу *вино́сити* — *вино́шувати*) розрізняється, між іншими, у таких дієсловах:

> *розрізня́ти, розрізня́ю… — розрі́знювати, розрі́знюю…
>
> виснажа́ти, виснажа́ю… — висна́жувати, висна́жую…
>
> вивча́ти, вивча́ю… — виу́чувати, виу́чую…
>
> виловля́ти, виловля́ю… — вило́влювати, вило́влюю…
>
> вихваля́ти, вихваля́ю… — вихва́лювати, вихва́люю…
>
> розміря́ти, розміря́ю… — розмі́рювати, розмі́рюю…
>
> поруша́ти, поруша́ю… — пору́шувати, пору́шую…
>
> відзнача́ти, відзнача́ю… — відзна́чувати, відзна́чую…
>
> обміня́ти, обміня́ю… — обмі́нювати, обмі́нюю…
>
> виповня́ти, виповня́ю… — випо́внювати, випо́внюю…
>
> відтворя́ти, відтворя́ю… — відтво́рювати, відтво́рюю…* тощо.

Взагалі ж сприростковані недоконані форми дієслів, особливо із наростками *‑у‑* (*‑ува‑*) та *‑а‑* (*‑я‑*), дуже поширені в українській мові. Часто при тім у них буває змінений голосний кореня супроти форм несприросткованих недоконаних: *текти* — *утікати*, *терти* — *витирати* і т. ін. — див. [§ 16](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/zvukozminy).

В основі сприросткованих недоконаних форм дієслів здебільшого лежить пень наворотний (*носити* — *виношувати*, *виношати*, *бігати* — *забіга́ти* і т. ін.), коли ж у дієслова безнаросткова недоконана форма тільки одна, то ця друга (паросткова) форма недоконана буде з наростком (*‑в‑*) *‑а‑*:

> *глядіти — наглядати
>
> гріти — підігрівати
>
> грати — награвати
>
> знати — пізнавати…* або з наростком *‑ува‑* (*‑у‑*):
> *питати — напитувати
>
> писати — надписувати
>
> гуляти — нагулювати
>
> порядкувати — впорядкувати
>
> дарувати — роздаровувати
>
> мордувати — замордовувати
>
> танцювати — витанцьовувати
>
> обґрунтувати — обґрунтовувати
>
> обʼєктувати — виобʼєктовувати* і т. ін.

Зрідка сприростковані недоконані (другі) форми бувають і з безприросткових (перших) протяжних форм, напр., не тільки *виламувати* (*зламати*), а й *виломлювати* (*зломити*), не тільки *вилазити* (*злазити*), а й *вилізати* (*злізти*). Такі сприростковані форми від протяжних безнаросткових зʼявляються тим звичайніше, чим ті безнаросткові протяжні форми дуже відокремлюються від споріднених (безприросткових) наворотних, тобто чим більше стають сами наворотними, напр.

> *виси́джувати і висіда́ти
>
> вико́чувати і вика́чувати
>
> виле́жувати і виляга́ти,*

бо й

> *сидіти — сідати
>
> котити — качати
>
> лежати — лягати*

більше й дещо інак відрізняються одно від одного, ніж, напр., звичайні протяжні — наворотні як

> *нести — носити
>
> летіти — літати
>
> тягти — тягати* тощо. Порівн. § 86<sub>2</sub> дріб. шрифт.

Сприростковані дієслова взагалі і зокрема недоконані іноді існують у мові без відповідних несприросткованих, або без звʼязку з ними, напр.: *виснажати*, *підперезати* (*перезати* майже ніколи не вживається), *виповняти* (*повнити* теж майже не *вживається*), *відтворити* (не має звʼязку з *творити*) тощо.